# UICollectionViewCell - different layout for different size classes

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, size-classes

I have a simple `UICollectionViewCell` with one image and a label. In regular-regular size class I want the image to be on top, and the label below it. This is what it looks like in the Xcode's preview tab:

[image]

In any other size class I want the image to be on the left, and the label on the right:

[image]

I setup the constraints this way:

ImageView has following constraints:

- leading and top constraints for Any-Any
- fixed width and height for Any-Any

The label has following constraints:

- trailing constraint to Superview -  for Any-Any
- top constraint to the ImageView - only for Regular-Regular
- leading constraint to Superview - only for Regular-Regular
- top constraint to Superview - for Any-Any but not for Regular-Regular
- leading constraint to ImageView - for Any-Any but not for Regular-Regular

I also implemented the method to return the different cell size based on the current trait collection:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if (traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Regular) {
      return CGSizeMake(240, 194)
    }
    else {
      return CGSizeMake(340, 128)
    }
  }
```

The cell looks fine in the preview, and everything works fine when I run it on iPhone (e.g Compact-Regular). However, auto layout breaks when I run it on iPad:

[image]

And of course I get a bunch of warnings in the debug console: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

So, I guess the question is - what is the proper way of setting up the cell for different size classes?

I created a github repo with a [demo project](https://github.com/almas73/UICollectionViewCell_sizeClass)

Thanks!

Comment: if you support only iOS 9 and later, you can do that by using stackView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is disable those constraints for the Regular-Regular size class like you have, but also change their priority to < 1000 (i.e. not required). That way it will instead use the higher priority constraints for the specific size class.

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, even though it is a bit counterintuitive that you have to change the priority in order to make the auto layout to use proper constraints. Isn't uninstalling constraint a clear enough indication for auto layout engine that I don't want it there for this particular size class? I'll wait a couple more days, and if there will be no better answer, then I'll accept and give you a bounty =) Thanks!

Comment: @almas I thought about this some more and my take is that the constraint isn't actually removed. The way around it would be to explicitly set it for all other size classes so that you could disable the top level "Installed" checkmark. See my updated PR on your repo which still works simply by lowering the priority.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but my attempts to do this in the past have led to more pain with Autolayout size classes and I found the best solution was:

1. Have a separate nib for for each size class and then layout out the views in each as needed.
2. Have separate `CollectionViewFlowLayouts` for each size class and then transition between them when the size changes.

Following this pattern the cell size would be determined by the `collectionViewFlowlayout` rather than `sizeForItem...` and you will have more control over other parameters such as `sectionInset` and `minimumLineSpacing` etc. which often need varying when changing size classes in a collection view.

Here are the code changes that worked for me:

```
  let cellIdentifierCompact = "CustomCellCompact"
  let cellIdentifierRegular = "CustomCellReg"

  lazy var compactLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(240, 194)
    return layout
  }()

lazy var regLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(320, 128)
    return layout
  }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customCellNib = UINib(nibName: cellIdentifierCompact, bundle: nil)
    self.collectionView.registerNib(customCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifierCompact)

    let customCellNibReg = UINib(nibName: cellIdentifierRegular, bundle: nil)
    self.collectionView.registerNib(customCellNibReg, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifierRegular)
    self.configureLayoutForSize()
  }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cellId = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout == self.regLayout ? cellIdentifierRegular : cellIdentifierCompact
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
  }

  func configureLayoutForSize(){
    switch self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass{
    case UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular:
      self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.regLayout, animated: false)
    case .Compact, .Unspecified:
      self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.compactLayout, animated: false)
    }
  }

  override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.configureLayoutForSize()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Dallas. I'm sure there are many workarounds for this issue, including the one that you suggest. However, I think having multiple nibs and flow layouts is an overkill, especially for such a simple cell layout. Ideally I would like to understand what is wrong with my implementation - is it an iOS bug, or is there a bug in my code/nib?